# jQuery DataTables sDom order not work

Tags: javascript, datatables

I need the "filter" in the upper left side and the "size" in the upper right side, but is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#example').dataTable({
            "sDom": '<"top"fl>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">'
        });
} );
```

Why?

Comment: Hi Alisson, can you explain what you mean with "is not working"?

Comment: Does not display error.It works correctly. Just does not follow the order I want. Must appear the search input before number of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

- Use these two CSS rules to target all data tables:

  ```css
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
    float: left;
  }

  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length {
    float: right;
  }
  ```
- Use these two CSS rules to target `#example` data table:

  ```css
  #example_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
    float: left;
  }

  #example_wrapper .dataTables_length {
    float: right;
  }
  ```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvg8L5aa/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: @Alisson, sorry, corrected error in my code, thanks for pointing that out.